# wx.ScrolledWindow not repainting when scrolled

Tags: python, windows-7, wxpython, wxwidgets

I have a little app that I am working on with wxPython.

I have a scrolled window using `wx.ScrolledWindow`. It seems to refuse to repaint the contents when it is scrolled.

Example:
[image: Yes, my window-manager color-scheme is Pink. What of it?]

Code that created above example:

```
import wx


class SaveEdFrame(wx.Frame):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwds):
        kwds["style"] = wx.DEFAULT_FRAME_STYLE|wx.EXPAND
        wx.Frame.__init__(self, *args, **kwds)

        self.__do_layout()

        self.Bind(wx.EVT_SIZE, self.onSize)


    def __mainSizer(self):
        self.mainSizer = wx.BoxSizer(wx.VERTICAL)

        for key in xrange(30):
            self.headerLabel = wx.StaticText(self, -1, "TestStr %s" % key)
            self.mainSizer.Add(self.headerLabel)
        return self.mainSizer


    def __do_layout(self):
        ## begin wxGlade: SaveEdFrame.__do_layout

        self.scroll = wx.ScrolledWindow(self, style=wx.FULL_REPAINT_ON_RESIZE)
        self.scroll.SetScrollbars(1, 10, 1, 10)
        self.scroll.SetSizer(self.__mainSizer())


    def onSize(self, event):
        self.scroll.SetSize(self.GetClientSize())

        self.Refresh()


if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = wx.App(0)

    mainFrame = SaveEdFrame(None)
    app.SetTopWindow(mainFrame)
    mainFrame.Show(True)
    app.MainLoop()
```

I've been digging through the wxDocs, and it seems to me that one solution would be to subclass `wx.ScrolledWindow`, manually catch `wx.EVT_SCROLLWIN` events, and then explicitly redraw the window, but my attempts to do that failed when calling `self.Refresh()` did not cause the interior of the `wx.ScrolledWindow` to repaint.

Anyways, it seems to me that the whole point of the `wx.ScrolledWindow` object is that it should handle repainting itself when scrolled.

What am I doing wrong?

Platform is W7-x64, python 2.7 32 bit, wxPython 2.8.11.0

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think the problem there is that your wx.StaticText widgets are children of the SaveEdFrame, not the ScrolledWindow.  The ScrolledWindow is being redrawn over them as you scroll it.  Try:

```
 headerLabel = wx.StaticText(self.scroll, -1, "TestStr %s" % key)
 self.mainSizer.Add(headerLabel)
```

Comment: Yep. That fixed it. Also: Doh!

Comment: I think I was thinking of the ScrolledWindow as a Sizer, rather than a Panel.